# Windows authentication is allowing to access web site only for IIS Administrators and not for other users why?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

I am facing an issue with windows authentication in IIS. I have a website which is intranet site. But the problem is that only the admins of IIS can use it, not the other users in the same intranet. Windows authentication pop up is showing but after entering the username and password it is displaying the same authentication pop up.

Comment: any help on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found the answer to this, it might help someone who will be stuck like me. The problem was in the security tab we did not add user Account as "Users". We had all the accounts like IIS_USRS,admin, etc but we forgot to add "Users". After adding it allowed everyone to access the site.

The strange thing is when your application doesn't need Windows authentication then IIS_USRS are enough otherwise don't forget to add "Users" or whatever account needed to access.

Answer (score 0):

This can normally happen, by permissions a bad configuration of permissions.
Try doing some of the following options.

1.Verify that the user of the "**Applications Pools**" where the app is running, has the necessary permissions in the location where the app is located.

2.Verify that you have "**Windows Authentication**" enabled in your app. (Of course this is only if your app requires *Windows Authentication* if your app does not require *Windows Authentication* only activates **Anonymous Authetincation** and deactivates the others.)

3.Verify your app providers are set in this order for Windows Authentication(**NTLM,Negotiate**)

Comment: I have verified my app pools and it is running separately for each website. Also i have enabled windows authentication both in my web config and iis. But still facing the same issue. Any help?

Comment: Verify that the users is running the **Applications Pools(IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool or whatever user your configure)**, have rights in the folder where the app is running **(c:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourAppName)**

Comment: i have verified and i have given full access for IIS_USRS in my folder. But still not working. Authentication working only for logged in IIS users and not for people outside it.

Comment: all your user are in the same domain controller?

Comment: What do you mean by same domain controller? Can you brief it